# Excel: How to count total number of unique values based on a value from a different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate total number of orders based on a referral indicator. In my table I have 3 columns.

```
order_id (a), sku (b), referral (c)
9073765908  19333476    EMP_BC
9073765908  18717916    EMP_BC
9073741228  23224786    EMP_BC
9073729088  15870816    EMP_BC
9073238838  15927306    EMP_BC
9073216258  23210836    EMP_BC
9073216258  18709096    EMP_BC
9073216258  18705756    EMP_BC
9073169568  19333496    EMP_BC
9073169168  18714626    EMP_BC
9072921778  22723516    EMP_ES
9072921778  18708696    EMP_ES
9072921778  15933746    EMP_ES
9072910758  23223526    EMP_BC
9072910758  23184416    EMP_BC
9072910758  21081716    EMP_BC
9072910758  18704496    EMP_BC
9072895968  21082646    EMP_ES
9072856628  28685906    EMP_BC
9072856628  23795646    EMP_BC
9072856628  21447106    EMP_BC
9072856628  15936966    EMP_BC
```

Here is all the things I've tried thus far:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C, "=EMP_BC")
```

However this returns total including the duplicates.

Also tried this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS(A:A, A:A, C:C, "=EMP_BC"))
```

This however, causes my excel to freeze... Im assuming this is due to the number of records I have... I have over 60K records.

[edit]
I am expected the following result:

```
for EMP_BC: 8
because the following order_id is unique and the referral is EMP_BC:
9073765908
9073741228
9073729088
9073238838
9073216258
9073169568
9072910758
9072856628
```

I currently have a tab specifically setup so that it can have data copied and pasted in a tab. Another tab with all the formulas will reference the data and display the results. 
This one metric is giving me a lot of problems.

Any recommendations?

Comment: It is a little unclear what you want to do. What value do you expect the formula to return for that table, and how (step by step) did you determine that that is the correct result?

Comment: No because I want to attribute that EMP_BC had 8 unique orders. I just want a 'numeric' value to return counting the unique order IDs where referral column = 'emp_bc'

Comment: As @pnuts wrote, why are you excluding `9073169168` from your expected result.  If you included it, there would be 9 orders.  And if you use the pivot table, you can filter on referrals; collapse the result, and then use the `SUBTOTAL` function to count only the visible rows.

Comment: My mistake that should be included and returned 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an array formula that should accomplish what you want.  To enter an array formula, hold down `ctrl-shift` while hitting `enter`.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula.

```
=SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIFS(order_id,order_id,referral,"EMP_BC"),0))
```

This formula assumes the ranges comprise just the used range, and not the entire column.

It is possible that a User Defined Function written in VBA will execute much faster, even with limited range references.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), `alt-F11` opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select `Insert/Module` and paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like `=UniqueOrdersByReferral(order_id,referral,"EMP_BC")` in some cell.

---

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 'Comment out this line to make case SENSITIVE
Function UniqueOrdersByReferral(rOrderID As Range, rReferral As Range, sReferralCode As String) As Long
    Dim Col As Collection
    Dim I As Long, vOID As Variant, vREF As Variant

vOID = rOrderID
vREF = rReferral

If UBound(vOID) <> UBound(vREF) Then
    MsgBox "Order ID and Referral Ranges must be of same size"
    Exit Function
End If

Set Col = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(vOID)
    If vREF(I, 1) = sReferralCode Then Col.Add vOID(I, 1), CStr(vOID(I, 1))
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

UniqueOrdersByReferral = Col.Count

End Function
```

---

Comment: I've tried that but with 60k rows the dupe check seems to kill excel and hangs it. Though you have an if error I'll see if that Makes a difference.

Comment: @Rick Without the `IFERROR`, you will wind up with DIV/0 errors; and the `=` sign before `EMP_BC` is superfluous

Comment: @Rick  Also, try using ranges that encompass just the used range; (no blanks).  See if that speeds things up.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I will try the udf method and report back.

Comment: Ron, that worked beautifully. Thank you! You saved me lots of headaches. My last resort was to use a pivot table... Just with the format limitations (aesthetically), i was trying to avoid it.

Comment: @Rick I'm curious as to how long the UDF method took to run on your data.

Comment: the UDF took only seconds if even.

Comment: @Rick Thanks.  Sometimes these methods hit a snag when dealing with large amounts of data.  Sounds like the UDF works well enough, though.